# Combining multiple lambda expressions into one line

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, lambda

implement in one line, using lambda expressions(map/filter/reduce),
function that gets list of different types and returns a dictionary which has these keys:
{‘c’: , ‘i’: , ‘f’: , ‘o’: }

'c' will present list of characters
'i' list of the integers
'f' list of the floats
'o' list of any other types

for exaple for the list:
myList = ['a', 2, 3, 's', 2.23]

the output will be:
{'c': ['a', 's'], 'i': [2, 3], 'f': [2.23], 'o': []}

So far is I made a method of it that works but I'll need somehow change it one line of code:

```
def q1a(myList):
   myDict = dict.fromkeys(('c', 'i', 'f', 'o'))
   myDict['c'] = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is str, myList))
   myDict['i'] = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is int, myList))
   myDict['f'] = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is float, myList))
   myDict['o'] = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is not float and type(x) is not int and type(x) is not str, myList))
   return myDict
```

Comment: Not everything should be reduced to a functional one-liner in Python. This is much better accomplished using a boring `for` loop that updates a `dict` one value at a time. If I had to do this in one line, I would use `itertools.groupby` and a function that takes a value and returns the single-letter "category" for the type of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below ugly one-liner

```
out = dict(zip(['c','i','f','o'], map(list, (filter(lambda x:isinstance(x,str), lst), filter(lambda x:isinstance(x,int), lst), filter(lambda x:isinstance(x,float), lst), filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x,(str,float,int)), lst)))))
```

You can also use `functools.reduce` with a helper function (not exactly one liner but doesn't need multiple `filter`s so saves time):

```
def add(d, x):
    d[x[0]].append(x[1])
    return d
from functools import reduce
out = reduce(add, 
             map(lambda x: (('c',x) if isinstance(x,str) 
                            else (('i',x) if isinstance(x,int) 
                                  else (('f',x) if isinstance(x,float) 
                                        else ('o',x)))), lst), 
             {'c':[],'i':[],'f':[],'o':[]})
```

Output:

```
{'c': ['a', 's'], 'i': [2, 3], 'f': [2.23], 'o': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets around the need to assign to the keys one at a time:

```py
def q1a(myList):
   return {
       'c': list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is str, myList)),
       'i': list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is int, myList)),
       'f': list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is float, myList)),
       'o': list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is not float and type(x) is not int and type(x) is not str, myList))
   }
```

Comment: What about a list comprehension?

Comment: OP asked for using map/reduce/filter explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions and create a dictionary literal:

```
{
    'c': [e for e in myList if type(e) is str],
    'i': [e for e in myList if type(e) is int],
    'f': [e for e in myList if type(e) is float],
    'o': [e for e in myList if type(e) not in {float, int, str}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment seems to be asking you to take a functional approach to this and create a single operation.

One option would be a single reduce that manipulates a dict. This isn't as natural in python as in other languages because most dict operations return None. But you can still do it in a functional way if you try (it's a one-liner broken up for a (minor) improvement in readability):

```
from functools import reduce

l = ['a', 2, 3, 's', 2.23]

res = reduce(
    lambda d, t: dict(d, **{t[1]: d[t[1]] + [t[0]]}),
    map(lambda el: (el, {str: 'c', int: 'i', float: 'f'}.get(type(el), 'o')) , l),
    dict.fromkeys('cifo', [])
)

print(res)
# {'c': ['a', 's'], 'i': [2, 3], 'f': [2.23], 'o': []}
```

This works by creating a list of tuples with the `map()`:

```
list(map(lambda el: (el, {str: 'c', int: 'i', float: 'f'}.get(type(el), 'o')) , l),)
# [('a', 'c'), (2, 'i'), (3, 'i'), ('s', 'c'), (2.23, 'f')]
```

and then updating a dict inside the reduce that is initialized with empty lists created with `dict.fromkeys('cifo', [])`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm writing this in Python, my first choice would be to skip the functional approach and use a boring `for` loop and a `default` dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def q1a(myList):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for v in myList:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            type_code = 'c'
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            type_code = 'i'
        elif isinstnace(v, float):
            type_code = 'f'
        else:
            type_code = 'o'
        d[tc].append(v)
    return d
```

However, this suggests a solution using `itertools.groupby`. The big `if` statement makes for a simple function like

```
def type_code(v):
    if isinstance(v, str):
        type_code = 'c'
    elif isinstance(v, int):
        type_code = 'i'
    elif isinstnace(v, float):
        type_code = 'f'
    else:
        type_code = 'o'
    return type_code
```

which could be written as a single conditional expression suitable for use in a lambda expression:

```
 lambda v: ('c' if isinstance(v, str) else 
            'i' if isinstance(v, int) else
            'f' if isinstance(v, float) else
            'o')
```

In the following, I'll abbreviate the above lambda expression as `tc` for readability.

With `itertools.groupby`, you can partition a (sorted) list using a function that specifies which partition each element belongs to. The partitions so produced are suitable for use in a dict comprehension.

```
from itertools import groupby

def q1a(myList):
    return {k: list(vs) for k, vs in groupby(sorted(myList, key=tc), tc)}
```

One slight glitch:

```
>>> q1a(['a', 2, 3, 's', 2.23])
{'c': ['a', 's'], 'f': [2.23], 'i': [2, 3]}
```

The result doesn't include a key that isn't produced by a value in the list.  You'll have to merge the result with pre-initialized `dict` containing all the keys.

```
def q1a(myList):
    return ({'c': [], 'i': [], 'f': [], 'o': []}
            | {k: list(vs) for k, vs in groupby(sorted(myList, key=tc), tc)})
```

I don't use `dict.fromKeys("cifo", [])` because then each key defaults to a reference to the *same* empty list, rather than a distinct empty list for each.

Comment: What about building a typecode map using `dict` or even `defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a double indirection to convert types into letters and setdefault to update the resulting dictionary:

```
def q1a(myList):
    types  = {str:'c', int:'i', float:'f'}
    myDict = dict()
    for x in myList:
        myDict.setdefault(types.get(type(x),'o'),[]).append(x)
    return myDict

myList = ['a', 2, 3, 's', 2.23]
print(q1a(myList))
{'c': ['a', 's'], 'i': [2, 3], 'f': [2.23]}
```

Using a defaultdict could simplify it a bit:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def q1a(myList):
    types  = defaultdict(lambda:'o',{str:'c', int:'i', float:'f'})
    myDict = defaultdict(list)
    for x in myList:
        myDict[types[type(x)]].append(x)
    return dict(myDict)
```